# Is propanol 1-2 diol 178 the same as propylene glycol?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, terminology, alcohols, solvents, cleaning

I clean vinyl records in an ultrasonic vinyl record cleaning machine the manual states it uses propanol 1-2 diol 178 as a surfactant.  I think this is the same chemical as propylene glycol. Is it?

Comment: @Thomas A Jones — It is probably a different compound. First, "propanol 1-2 diol" is not a proper chemical name. Also the "178" part is weird. It rather gives the idea of the compound being a polymer, which would fit its role as a surfactant. By definition, a surfactant needs a polar (electron-rich) part AND a lipophilic (carbon-rich) part.

Comment: Make sure you are asking about the right name. Also, online search is your friend. Could be 1,2-Propanediol, with n=178 the degree of polymerization, thus PG. Or 178 could be the avg molecular weight, then n is about 2. Maybe something else.

Comment: I bought propylene glycol to use it as surfactant for the ultrasonic vinyl record cleaning machine. It is not the same as this does not get in the grooves, it stays on the surface and does not pull out the "white toothpaste".
What ever it is the price for the surfactant is much to high as it is 98%destilled water.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, “propanol 1-2 diol 178” is the same compound as propylene glycol and appears to be a fabricated name used in a manual for a proprietary [cleaning system by Kirmuss Audio](https://kirmussaudio.com/ka-rc-1-ultrasonic-record-restoration-system/).
According to the article from Analog Corner magazine [[1, p. 22](https://kirmussaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/STEREOPHILE-FREMER-JULY-2019-KirmussAudio-2.pdf)] (emphasis on the footnote):

> The Kirmuss Audio KA-RC-1 comes with accessories: 60 mL of an antibacterial/antistatic/antifungal spray; a goat­ hair brush applicator; an optical-quality microfiber cloth; a larger microfiber cloth (decorated with rabbits) to cover the work space; a circular felt mat to support the record during hand cleaning; a combination carbon fiber/parastatic felt brush; and a bottle of stylus cleaner.
>
> All of this costs $870—far less than at least one competing system and only
> slightly more than the iSonic machine and its inferior record-spinning mechanism.
> Granted, the accessories are not costly, but no matter how you figure it, Kirmuss doesn’t seem to be in this for the money: He’s not looking to *lose* money, but clearly he’s not trying to make a killing.
> From what I’ve witnessed, he’s more concerned with waging a worldwide war against fungus.
>
> The antibacterial/antistatic spray is identified in the manual as a “98-99% distilled water, 1-2% propanol 1-2 diol 178 mix.” That last one is propyl­ene glycol,<sup>4</sup> an organic solvent used in, among other things, pharmaceutical preparations and as a food additive.
>
> ---
>
> 4 That chemical name seems made-up, and Kirmuss at first disputed that the ingredient was nothing more than propylene glycol, but a subsequent correspondence made it clear.

#### Reference

1. Michael Fremer. The Seven “M”s of the Charles Kirmuss Vinyl Restoration System. *Analog Corner*, July **2019**. ([PDF](https://kirmussaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/STEREOPHILE-FREMER-JULY-2019-KirmussAudio-2.pdf), accessed 2020-09-03)